# Error when using starflut package in flutter on an emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies, python-embedding

I am trying to run a python script from flutter using the starflut package. I followed this tutorial https://smazee.com/blog/how-to-run-the-python-code-in-the-flutter-app online.

When I run the this app on the android emulator, the app just starts and stops working almost immediately. I added the files, edited the pubspec.yaml file exactly like in the tutorial.

[image]

Here is the stacktrace.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /home/mohammed/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/starflut-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/srplab/starflut/StarflutPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:44167/d9KBdipLkhE=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
I/skeletonproc_module,32084( 9168): create service group[0], community 32bit for android_x86, version[3.7.6.260] @www.srplab.com
I/skeletonproc_module,32087( 9168): "SetRegisterCode" function can be used to change it to professional version dynamically 
I/skeletonproc_module,32132( 9168): lua engine[Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio]
I/skeletonproc_module,1592( 9168): create service success[test]
I/flutter ( 9168): docPath = /data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files
I/flutter ( 9168): resPath = /data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files
I/flutter ( 9168): -1  1   load library [/data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstar_python36.so] success....   6
I/skeletonproc_module,48755( 9168): load library [/data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstar_python36.so] success....
D/starcore( 9168): Begin call _PyCodecRegistry_Init
D/starcore( 9168): import encodings failed....
D/starcore( 9168): ZipImportError("can't decompress data; zlib not available",)
D/starcore( 9168): /data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files:/data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files/python3.6.zip:/data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files/libs:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files:/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python26.zip
D/starcore( 9168): Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
F/libc    ( 9168): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 9218 (Thread-2), pid 9168 (testingstarflut)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:11/RSR1.201013.001/6903271:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2021-04-12 23:22:39+0300
pid: 9168, tid: 9218, name: Thread-2  >>> com.example.testingstarflut <<<
uid: 10154
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    eax 00000000  ebx 000023d0  ecx 00002402  edx 00000006
    edi f033f81e  esi b57f9e10
    ebp f1bedb90  esp b57f9db8  eip f1bedb99
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
      #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #02 pc 00076511  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+209) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #03 pc 0016454e  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libpython3.6m.so (Py_FatalError+46)
      #04 pc 00165837  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libpython3.6m.so (_Py_InitializeEx_Private+1575)
      #05 pc 001658a3  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libpython3.6m.so (Py_InitializeEx+35)
      #06 pc 000668bb  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstar_python36.so (libstar_python36_ScriptInit+1435)
      #07 pc 003a2faf  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstarcore.so (SkeletonProc_ActiveScriptInterface(char*, char*, void*)+1711)
      #08 pc 003a3d4d  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstarcore.so (SkeletonProc_GetScriptInterface(char*)+45)
      #09 pc 00249569  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstarcore.so (ClassOfVSBasicSRPInterface::InitRaw(char const*, ClassOfSRPInterface*)+201)
      #10 pc 00046da4  /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/lib/x86/libstar_java.so (Java_com_srplab_www_starcore_StarCoreFactory_SrvGroup_1InitRaw+132)
      #11 pc 00142132  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+82) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #12 pc 0013b922  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #13 pc 001d0381  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+241) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #14 pc 00386701  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+385) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #15 pc 0037aa3e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1070) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #16 pc 007a11b7  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+967) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #17 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #18 pc 000e6a00  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/base.apk] (com.srplab.www.starcore.StarSrvGroupClass._InitRaw+4)
      #19 pc 007a14fe  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #20 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #21 pc 000da844  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/base.apk] (com.srplab.starflut.StarflutPlugin.onMethodCall_Do+16476)
      #22 pc 007a14fe  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #23 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #24 pc 000d59ba  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/base.apk] (com.srplab.starflut.StarflutPlugin$3$1.handleMessage+98)
      #25 pc 007a14fe  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #26 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #27 pc 0036f24e  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x92b000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
      #28 pc 007a14fe  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #29 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #30 pc 00396a36  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x92b000) (android.os.Looper.loop+482)
      #31 pc 007a505e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1454) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #32 pc 00135921  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #33 pc 000d5c3c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~Pz2q5K_lcSeJqMyQDrqbkQ==/com.example.testingstarflut-t77OZVkgJ2M-t5U46Khxzg==/base.apk] (com.srplab.starflut.StarflutPlugin$3.run+100)
      #34 pc 007a355e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+2126) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #35 pc 001359a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #36 pc 000eb7d0  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
      #37 pc 0036fb02  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.16375758241455872412)+370) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #38 pc 00379b00  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+176) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #39 pc 0078b325  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1061) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #40 pc 0014220d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #41 pc 0013b922  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #42 pc 001d0381  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+241) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #43 pc 0062f37c  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+620) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #44 pc 0062f595  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+85) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #45 pc 00697701  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1537) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #46 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #47 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
Lost connection to device.
```

I am not sure what the problem is, but I feel like this part in the stacktrace is the reason

`D/starcore( 9168): /data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files:/data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files/python3.6.zip:/data/data/com.example.testingstarflut/files/libs:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files:/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python26.zip`

I don't know how to fix it. Please help!